# HTML email coding

Tags: html, email, styles

I am altering an html email template created by previous designer. It doesn't look right to me:

```html
<html style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
```

I would have thought 'style' goes into 'head' and 'html style="..." looks confusing. I am not an expert on html emails, just thought somebody here might be more knowledgeable 
Also is there meant to be a doctype?

Comment: Yeah, that's uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was likely done because many email clients strip out the `head` element. However, the `style` element should go in the `body` element at point. The only supported child elements of `html` are `head` and `body`. Of course, even then, many email clients also strip out style elements, so really all CSS in an email template should be inline for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Newsletter code is based on tables and all its styles are placed inline. Code like this looks archaic but there is a good reason for this - most email services don’t allow for proper positioning and shaping the format using such tags
as div, section etc. and that’s why tables are used to build a newsletter.

See: http://freshmail.com/developers/best-practices-for-email-coding/ for a reference of what styling can and cannot be used. The guide includes also advice for newsletter designers and developers regarding Responsive Email Design